# Internet Explorer empty div link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to make an empty div react to click.

HTML

```
<div id="closeButton"></div>
```

CSS

```
#closeButton {
height:100px;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
width:100px;    
z-index:1000;
border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
alert("yo");
});
```

This works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. Why?

Comment: which IE? 6? 7? 8? all? what happens if you put some content into the div (just one line of text for testing)? Are there any other elements that might be invisible and lay above of your div?

Comment: IE8 and if i put some text in the div it works. I can click text

Comment: And if i put background-color on the div i can click it too.

Comment: why it's a <div>? you gave it ID "closeBUtton" :D

Comment: Invisible 'buttons' that you can only hit with a pointing device aren't the most accessible of controls. Please don't do this.

Comment: It doesn't really matter why the OP wants to do this. I'm having the same issue and it would help if someone would just answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by adding a 1x1 transparent png as background-image. This made the div render properly and possible to use for click functions.

Comment: thank you! I don't know why I never thought of this. Also you can download a transparent gif here: http://www.golivetutor.com/tutorials/misc/transparent.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a wierd bug, and the only [solution](http://jsbin.com/ivoqu4/9) is to set IE in HTML4 standards-compliant mode

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#closeButton').click(function(){
      alert("yo");
  });
})
```